# Laravel FileManager iconv() expects exactly 3 parameters, 4 given?

Tags: laravel, utf-8, laravel-5.4, file-manager

I have tried the following:

```
iconv('ISO-8859-1', 'UTF-8//IGNORE', 'BIG5', $input);
```

However, it fails and produces this [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3aWtW.png):

> iconv() expects exactly 3 parameters, 4 given

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the official documentation:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.iconv.php

You're passing an extra argument to the function.